# Yarn errors with Not Found for local Lerna packages

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna

Calling yarn commands inside a package that references a local lerna package fails with

```
- packages
  - package1
  - package2
```

say package2 references package1

```
 dependencies: [
"@my-scope/package1": "^1.0.0"]
```

When I run any `yarn` command in package2 e.g. yarn add, or yarn list I get an error:

> An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope%2package1: Not found".

I have run `lerna bootstrap` at the top level with

`"npmClient": "yarn"`

which successfully builds all my packages and the node_modules of package2 contains package1, however the yarn.lock file does not have any of the local packages

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your dependence version should match origin's version, otherwise, yarn will lookup by internet instead local package

Say

packages1's package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@my-scope/package1",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

packages2's package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@my-scope/package2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-scope/package1": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

yarn can's find that version match `^1.0.0`, so it just try fetch from yarnpkg.com